# Обособляется ли определительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастия, определения

С такой же скоростью мой кот вылез из ванны(,) весь испуганный и мокрый.
Нужно ли обособлять в данном случае оборот или нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Запятая ставится.
*С такой же скоростью мой кот вылез из ванны, **весь испуганный и мокрый***.

Определительный оборот не входит в состав сказуемого. На обособление также влияет распространённость первой части, а именно обстоятельство "с такой же скоростью". Если бы структура предложения была иной и акцент смещался на оборот (а всё это зависит от контекста), то тогда можно было бы говорить о том, что определения связаны по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым. Например, в урезанном варианте:

*Мой кот вылез из ванны исп**У**ганный и м**О**крый*. Здесь основная информация вложена в определения. В таких случаях, как говорится в справочнике, в определительном обороте может быть употреблена форма творительного падежа:
*Мой кот вылез из ванны испуганн**ым** и мокр**ым***.
В исходном предложении так не получится из-за местоимения "весь".

[**Обособленные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) [Розенталь, Согласованные определения, пункт 2, 3)]

> Если глагол со значением движения или состояния сам по себе служит сказуемым, то определительный оборот обособляется: *Трифон Иваныч выиграл у меня два рубля с полтиной и ушёл, **весьма довольный своей победой*** (Т.); *Перерыв ещё не кончился, а она уже стояла у станка, **побледневшая, гладенько причёсанная*** (Ник.); *И она пошла рядом со мною, **кряжистая, уверенная в своей силе*** (Гл.).

Также определения обособляются, если не находятся непосредственно при существительном:
*Небо раскрылось в вышине, **прозрачно-льдистое** и **голубое***.

Comment: Класс!  Голосую за обоих. Александр, а можно скроить из этого предложения  предложение со сказуемым, но при этом  рассматривать его как можно ближе к авторскому варианту? Что мешает?

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за оценку! :)  Можно, наверное. Мешает, думаю, "с такой же скоростью". Вообще, чтобы детальнее рассмотреть предложение и возможность включить оборот в сказуемое, нужен контекст.

Comment: Да. контест нужен, я тоже подумала об этом. Но  обст. оборот в начале предложения может быть детерминантом (небольшая пауза). Мне больше мешает частица "весь".  Ну и И.п. для сказуемого можно оставить.

Comment: Да, хотел написать и про "весь" тоже (поэтому я его и убрал из короткого варианта). Но вроде бы с ним можно.

Comment: Здесь же тоже можно заменить падежом: а она уже стояла у станка побледневшей, гладенько причёсанной. Разве нет?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец или тут дело именно в "у станка"? Тогда почему в наше примере "из ванны" не влияет? было бы понятно, если бы сказуемое стояло рядом с прилагательным: стояла побледневшей, вылез испуганный, но тут есть другие элементы между ними. а пунктуация разная.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Не думаю, что это будет корректным: *Перерыв ещё не кончился, а она уже стояла у станка побледневшей, гладенько причёсанной*. Как-то не вяжется у меня "стояла побледневшей". Да и разрыв с подлежащим сказывается. Хотя опять же,  мы не знаем контекста. В вашем предложении творит. падежом не заменить из-за "весь".

Comment: Мик Урри стоял побледневший, прекрасно понимая, насколько опасен был Индекс несколько минут назад

Comment: просто я о том, что этот критерий творительного падежа весьма туманнен.

Comment: Вот, в последнем примере хорошо выглядит без обособления. Акцент не на том, что он стоял, а какой при этом был. А в примере Розенталя наоборот, главное то, что она **уже стояла у станка**, хотя перерыв ещё не кончился. // Про туманность падежа согласен :)) Привёл эту информацию для общего понимания темы.

Comment: Для меня примеры, где глагол стоит рядом причастием или прилагательным, не вызывают вопросов. Сложность возникает тогда, когда что-то вклинивается между, и не всегда понятно, какой элемент способствует отделению, а какой нет.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ один — да. Причины две: во-первых, оборот после определяемого слова; во-вторых, он от него оторван.

> С такой же скоростью мой кот вылез из ванны, весь испуганный и мокрый.

Так как есть два определения и они — в конце, можно даже тире.

> С такой же скоростью мой кот вылез из ванны — весь испуганный и мокрый.