# Грамматическая основа в сложном предложении

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение, и, грамматическая-основа

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему после слова «вселяются» ставится запятая?
Не могу разобраться с грамматическими основами: 1 — она отправляется, 2 — жильцы вселяются, а 3 — ?

*Как только отправляется она зимой гулять,

Жильцы в дома вселяются, и в каждый — целых пять!*
Загадка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

❶ Союз "и", перед которым ставится запятая, относится в данном предложении к присоединительным.

> Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину или в конец предложения, отделяются или **выделяются запятыми** (реже — **тире**). Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами *даже, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, (да) и притом, причём, и («и притом»), да, да и, да и вообще, да и только* и др.: <...> *Вот тебе ужо будет баня, **и  с твоею хозяюшкою*** (П.)...

Теоретически в этом предложении перед "и" можно поставить точку.
*Как только отправляется она зимой гулять, жильцы в дома вселяются. И в каждый — целых пять!*

В Нацкорпусе русского языка (вот [ссылка](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=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) — пользуйтесь!) нашлось похожее по структуре предложение:
*Даже отсюда видно, как огромны ее глаза. И в каждом — по огоньку лампы* (Булат Окуджава. Новенький как с иголочки).

❷ *И в каждый — целых пять!* — это неполное предложение, в котором грамматическая основа восстанавливается из предыдущей части предложения.
И в каждый [дом вселяются] — целых пять [жильцов]!

Третья грамматическая основа: пять жильцов (счетный оборот) вселяются.

[Присоединительные члены предложения](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я невероятно рада! Огромное спасибо

Comment: @МарияАксёнова :))  Цитирую отрывок из своего комментария под первым вашим вопросом: "...а также **принимать** один из ответов на свой вопрос **галочкой**...". Но с этим не торопитесь, подождите хотя бы один день – могут появиться и другие ответы...

Comment: А я сразу на галочку нажала)

Comment: @МарияАксёнова Нет, не нажали. Галочка должна загореться зелёным цветом. Вот, например: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476117/Обособляется-ли-определительный-оборот/476123#476123

Comment: @МарияАксёнова Вот, теперь порядок 

Comment: Да, разобралась, спасибо)